# angular prevent state change user not login

Tags: angularjs, authentication

if user not login i want to prevent to state change . i'm use below code and work fine.

```
angular.module('app', [...])
       .config(function(){})
       .run(function($rootscope,$auth,$state){

       $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function(event){
        var user = $auth.getToken();
        if (user === null){
            // User isn’t authenticated
            $state.transitionTo("index");
            event.preventDefault();
         }
        });

       })
```

but show this errors !

```
angular.js:12783 RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
at Array.indexOf (native)
at indexOf (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js:87:18)
at http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js:1708:46
at forEach (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:341:20)
at http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js:1707:9
at forEach (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:341:20)
at Object.$$keys (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js:1706:7)
at Object.$$validate [as $$validates] (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js:1729:23)
at Object.transitionTo (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js:3184:27)
at http://localhost:9000/scripts/app.js:114:24
```

any one can help me?

Answer (score 1):

Your stateChangeStart function creates a loop, and that's why you are getting error. Consider this:

1. State change starts
2. User is not authenticated
3. State go to 'index'
4. State change starts
5. User is not authenticated
6. State go to 'index'

You could try with some variable for state that is only for authenticated users, for example:

```
  $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function(event, toState){
    if (toState.auth) {
      var user = $auth.getToken();

      if (!user) {
        // User isn’t authenticated
        event.preventDefault();
        $state.transitionTo("index");
     }
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this? and let me know.

```
angular.module('app', [...])
       .config(function(){})
       .run(function($rootscope,$auth,$state){

       $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function(event){
        var user = $auth.getToken();
        if (user === undefined){
            // User isn’t authenticated
            $state.transitionTo("index");
            event.preventDefault();
         }
        });

       })
```